# How to access Remote Desktop Connection Managers root settings?

Tags: remote-desktop

So, I recently discovered RDCM. It's pretty excellent, but I'm finding I have some settings I want to have on every computer, regardless of segment it's in. I see in the .rdg configuration window, I can Inherit settings from parent. I assume this allows me to inherit from a root parent that applies to all .rdg files. Unfortunately, I can't find it. Is this available somewhere, and if so, how do I apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see this checkbox: Inherit from Parent, **and it is checked**,
a big button below tells you where it is from.

For example: <kbd>Source: Default settings group</kbd>

Now, you may not have guessed it, but this button, you can actually click it. If you do so, you are being brought straight to the default group settings.

Otherwise, you can press *Tools* > *Settings* and on the *General* tab, you'll also find a button that brings you to the <kbd>Default group Settings...</kbd>.

Comment: Interesting. For my version I don't have that button that shows the source. I do however have the default settings group in the location you provided, so I'll edit that. Will maker as answer when the timeout expires. Just curious, what version of RDCM are you running? I have version 2.7.

Comment: Ohh, that button is available when I'm inheriting from parent, but hidden when using custom settings. Figures. It might be worth it to include in your answer that the button is missing if you are actively overriding settings.

Comment: 2.7 is the latest, and I'm using it too. Yeah, I figured you were inheriting the settings, otherwise you would not have asked for it... But I'll edit my answer. :) Glad I could help.